# Symfony CLI - There are no tasks defined in the "security" namespace

Tags: php, symfony, command-line-interface

In Symfony 4, when I try to run this command for security check in the terminal:

`symfony security:check --no-interaction`

I get this error message:

> There are no tasks defined in the "security" namespace.

[image: Error message]

Not sure what is wrong or what needs to be fixed.

Comment: There is no such command in Symfony 5

Comment: The command can be found here https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/security/security_checker.html

Comment: For Symfony 4 - yes. Not for Symfony 5 ir 6

Comment: As [repo warning](https://github.com/sensiolabs/security-checker) states: **underlying web service will stop working at the end of January 2021**

Comment: Ok, Symfony 4 then .. do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The `symfony` CLI is not part of a Symfony application. It is a standalone tool.

**Solution:**

Update your [symfony-cli](https://github.com/symfony-cli/symfony-cli) version to the latest version.

Installation instructions for various operating systems can be found in the documentation chapter: [Install Symfony CLI](https://symfony.com/download#step-1-install-symfony-cli)

Verify that you have the latest version (`v5.4.13` as of today).

```
symfony version
```

Then - inside your project directory - run:

```bash
symfony local:check:security
```

You can view all available sub-commands with:

```
symfony list
```